# Set JPA transactional isolation level to Serializable would be enough to deal with extreme concurrent condition?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, consistency

Extreme condition would be like there is only one or two products left but 1,000 people want to buy that at the very same time.

In this case, @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) would be enought to deal with it?

Or do I need to set @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) on JPA method either?

I know isolation level is about read consistency whether  lock is about write consistency but this is so confusing.

Any advise would be thankful!